# C++/CLI marshaling .NET delegate to native delegate

Tags: delegates, c++-cli, marshalling

I am trying to pass a delegate with managed parameters to native code to be invoked. My code below runs ok, but the string output is garbage.

## Native Class

### Header

```
#pragma once
typedef void (* SegmentCreatedDelegate)(char** arg);
public class SampleClass
{
public:
    SampleClass(void);
    ~SampleClass(void);
    void DoWork(SegmentCreatedDelegate callback);
};
```

### Code

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(void)
{
}

SampleClass::~SampleClass(void)
{

}

void SampleClass::DoWork(SegmentCreatedDelegate callback)
{
    for(int x = 0; x< 10; x++)
    {
        char* myStr2 = "newsegment!";
        callback(&myStr2);
    }
}
```

## Managed Class

### Header

```
#pragma once
public ref class SampleClassNet
{
public:
    delegate void SegmentCreatedDelegateNet(System::String^ arg);
    SampleClassNet(void);
    void DoWork(SegmentCreatedDelegateNet^ segmentCreatedCallback);
};
```

### Code

```
SampleClassNet::SampleClassNet(void)
{
}

void SampleClassNet::DoWork(SegmentCreatedDelegateNet^ segmentCreatedCallback)
{
    SampleClass* nativeClass = new SampleClass();
    System::IntPtr pointer = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(segmentCreatedCallback);
    nativeClass->DoWork((SegmentCreatedDelegate)(void*)pointer);
    System::GC::KeepAlive(segmentCreatedCallback);
}
```

This code runs fine with the follow c#.

```
var sampleClass = new SampleClassNet();
sampleClass.DoWork((Console.WriteLine));
```

Except I get the following output, instead of the expected 10 entries of "newsegment!".

```
(ÇÆX
(ÇÆX☺
(ÇÆX☻
(ÇÆX♥
(ÇÆX♦
(ÇÆX♣
(ÇÆX♠
(ÇÆX
(ÇÆX
(ÇÆX
```

Not exactly "newsegment!", but I am not sure why the marshaling is not working. Maybe I need I need some kind of "MarshalAs" attribute so that the System::String knows that I have 8-bit chars?

Comment: Your SegmentCreatedDelegateNet is lying, you say it gets a String^ but it is actually a char**.  Write a little helper method that converts it, then calls the managed delegate.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should convert the `char**` to a `String^`. (Btw, why pass `char**`, not `char*`? `String` has a constructer taking `char*`, which might simplify things a lot.)

I haven't tried the following, but you might give it a try:

```
public ref class SampleClassNet {
private:
    delegate void SegmentCreatedDelegateNative(char** str);
    SegmentCreatedDelegateNet^ managedCallback;
    SegmentCreatedDelegateNative^ nativeCallback;
    void printString(char** string);
public:
    delegate void SegmentCreatedDelegateNet(System::String^ arg);
    SampleClassNet();
    void DoWork(SegmentCreatedDelegateNet^ segmentCreatedCallback);
};

SampleClassNet::SampleClassNet() {
    nativeCallback = printString;
}

void SampleClassNet::DoWork(SegmentCreatedDelegateNet^ segmentCreatedCallback) {
    SampleClass* nativeClass = new SampleClass();
    managedCallback = segmentCreatedCallback;
    System::IntPtr pointer = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(nativeCallback);
    nativeClass->DoWork((SegmentCreatedDelegate)(void*)pointer);
}

void SampleClassNet::printString(char** string) {
    if (this->managedCallback != nullptr) {
        String^ str = gcnew String(*string);
        managedCallback(str);
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to use another delegate, `SegmentCreatedDelegateNative`, handed to the native class, and to call the actual managed delegate from the function associated with the wrapper.