# C++ CLI deleting unmanaged object automatically

Tags: memory-management, c++-cli, marshalling

I have a simple native class that creates small files in a directory every 9 seconds.

```
void SampleClass::DoWork(char *directoryPath, SegmentCreatedDelegate callback, bool *cancel)
{
    if(*cancel) return;

    char* segmentFileName = "test%d.ts";

    // open the file to write
    FILE *pFilempegTs = NULL;

    int segmentIndex = 0;
    clock_t beginingTime = clock();
    char currentSegmentPath[256];

    while(!*cancel)
    {
        // create the segment file to write if we haven't already.
        if(pFilempegTs == NULL)
        {
            segmentIndex++;
            strncpy(currentSegmentPath, directoryPath, sizeof(currentSegmentPath));
            strncat(currentSegmentPath, segmentFileName, sizeof(currentSegmentPath));
            sprintf(currentSegmentPath, currentSegmentPath, segmentIndex);
            if( (pFilempegTs  = fopen(currentSegmentPath, "wb" )) == NULL ) 
            {
                std::cout << "The file can not be opened for writing\n";
                return;
            }
        }

        if((double(clock() - beginingTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 9)
        {
            fclose(pFilempegTs);
            pFilempegTs = NULL;
            callback(currentSegmentPath); // the moment I invoke the delegate, the currentSegmentPath gets deleted.
            beginingTime = clock();
        }
    }  

    if(pFilempegTs != NULL)
    {
        fclose(pFilempegTs);
        callback(currentSegmentPath); // the moment I invoke the delegate, the currentSegmentPath gets deleted.
    }

    return;
}
```

This code works exactly as expected when the native class is compiled in a c++/cli project, and invoked via a .NET wrapper.

However, I get an error at `strncpy(currentSegmentPath, directoryPath, sizeof(currentSegmentPath))` if the native class is compiled in a native dll (not c++ cli) and executed. It seems that when I invoke the `SegmentCreatedDelegate`, the `currentSegmentPath` gets deleted in memory. Remember, this only happens when this `SampleClass` is in a native dll and called from c++/cli with `__declspec( dllexport )`.

NOTE: The `SegmentCreatedDelegate` is a managed-to-native delegate, created using the following code (.NET/c++/cli).

```
void SampleClassNet::DoWork(System::String^ directoryPath, SegmentCreatedDelegateNet^ segmentCreatedCallback, bool% cancel)
{
    SampleClass* nativeClass = new SampleClass();

    System::IntPtr directoryPathPointer = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(directoryPath);
    char *directoryPathNative = static_cast<char*>(directoryPathPointer.ToPointer());

    System::IntPtr callbackPointer = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(segmentCreatedCallback);

    pin_ptr<bool> pinnedCancel = &cancel;
    bool* pinnedCancelRef = pinnedCancel;

    nativeClass->DoWork(directoryPathNative, (SegmentCreatedDelegate)(void*)callbackPointer, pinnedCancelRef);

    System::GC::KeepAlive(segmentCreatedCallback);
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::FreeHGlobal(directoryPathPointer);
}
```

Why does invoking the `SegmentCreatedDelegate` delete `currentSegmentPath`, ONLY if the native method is compiled outside of the c++/cli project?

This is the exact error message I get.

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

**UPDATE**

I created a sample project to reproduce the issue.

https://bitbucket.org/theonlylawislove/so-c-cli-deleting-unmanaged-object-automatically

**UPDATE 2**

I added a `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention::Cdecl)]` attribute to my managed delegate and my issue seemed to be resolve. Both projects are using the cdecl calling convention, so I don't know why this was needed.

Comment: Don't do `(SegmentCreatedDelegate)(void*)callbackPointer` on an `IntPtr`.  Instead, `(SegmentCreatedDelegate)callbackPointer.ToPointer()`

Comment: Please also show the typedef of `SegmentCreatedDelegate`

Comment: You got the delegate declaration wrong in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054847/c-cli-marshaling-net-delegate-to-native-delegate), doesn't sound like you made progress.  That your previous code didn't crash was an unlucky accident.  The 'currentSegmentPath' variable can't be "deleted", it is a local variable.  You've been stuck on this long enough, to get the help you need you must post a small repro solution that demonstrates this issue to a file sharing service so we can actually repro the problem.

Comment: I created a sample project that you can reproduce the issue with. Run the program in release mode. https://bitbucket.org/theonlylawislove/so-c-cli-deleting-unmanaged-object-automatically

Answer (score 0):

It could be a conflict with calling conventions. As [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173253%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says, unmanaged and mixed assemblies uses [_cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) calling convertions, but for pure managed assemblies the builder uses [_clrcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec7sfckb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by default.

Try to compile both DLLs with the same calling convention. For VS 2010 this can be done into *Project properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Calling Convention*.